# Only show todays news - Silverstripe

Tags: php, date, operators, silverstripe

Hello Silverstripe Specialists!

I made the tutorial "extending a basic site"
(http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/tutorials/extending_a_basic_site)

That all worked very well so far.

I made this to show the latest news on the HomePage:
In HomePage.php:

```
// ...
public function LatestNews($num=5) {
    $holder = ArticleHolder::get()->First();
    return ($holder) ? ArticlePage::get()->filter('ParentID', 
        $holder->ID)->sort('Date DESC')->limit($num) : false;
}
```

And this in HomePage.ss:

```
// ...
public function LatestNews($num=5) {
    $holder = ArticleHolder::get()->First();
    return ($holder) ? ArticlePage::get()->filter('ParentID', 
        $holder->ID)->sort('Date DESC')->limit($num) : false;
}
```

That works very well!

Now my Question: All my News have a Date-Field. Is it possible to show only
the News of the current Date on the HomePage?

I tried this, but this wont work (Server Error) (`Datum` is my Date of the News):

```
public function LatestNews($num) {
    $holder = ArticleHolder::get()->First();
    return ($holder) ? ArticlePage::get()->filter('ParentID', "datum == CURDATE()", 
        $holder->ID)->sort('Date DESC')->limit($num) : false;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: filter could look like this?
->filter(array('ParentID' => $holder->ID, "datum:GreaterThanOrEqual" => date('Y-m-d')))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter()` needs either two values (column and value) or an array of key-value pairs of what to filter. So if you want to filter for more than one thing you need an array as parameter:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$todaysNews = ArticlePage::get()->filter(array(
    'ParentID' => $holder->ID, 
    'datum' => $today
));
```

This will return a [DataList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html) you can sort and limit like you did in your example.

See also in docs:

- [Data Model and ORM](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/) general overview
- [Search filters](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/) how to filter "greater than" etc...

**EDIT:**
So a method in your controller could look like:

```
public function getTodaysNews($num=5) {
    $holder = ArticleHolder::get()->First();
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    return $holder
        ? ArticlePage::get()->filter(array(
            'ParentID' => $holder->ID, 
            'datum' => $today
            ))->sort('Date DESC')->limit($num)
        : false;
}
```